# Must questions be asked in English?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

Must all the questions be asked in English?

If a question was asked in another language, would it be translated?

Comment: Meta SE discussion on this topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676/226928

Comment: I could have sworn that the FAQ used to specifically address this, but all I could find is this line regarding quality standards: [Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error)

Comment: If someone is having an issues with English, I would suggest that they write their question in their native tongue, then simply drop it into google translate. It'll come up with a fair approximation of English and I'm sure that either myself or another user would then correct any outstanding grammatical or spelling errors.

Answer (score 19):

Yes, all questions must be asked in English. If you are having trouble with a particular word or phrase, you might be able to get help with it on the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) SE site.

Comment: You can also ask for help in chat. I edited a question at least once when someone asked for ESL assistance in chat, so this does work

Comment: The fact that the qustions must be in English does not mean that only English-language works can be discussed here, does it?

Comment: @user14111 Not at all. We've had a few questions on Bollywood films, for example. They don't get as much attention as English works, but the language doesn't make them off-topic at all.